# Advancing numeric string in localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Working on a little task tracker applet that uses localstorage to both store tasks and keep a running tab of how many tasks have been created to date. The later is my issue.

Here's what I'm running, the issue is contained to variables "taskTracker" and "advanceTask".

```
function saveTask() {
        var task = $("#task").val();
        var taskDate = $("#taskDate").val();
        if (newUser == null) {
            var taskNumber = 0;
            localStorage.setItem("taskTracker", "0");
            localStorage.setItem("newUser", "no");
        }
        else {
            var taskNumber = localStorage.getItem("taskTracker");
        }
        var advanceTask = taskNumber + 1;
        localStorage.setItem('task' + taskNumber, task);
        localStorage.setItem('task' + taskNumber + 'date', taskDate);
        localStorage.setItem("taskTracker", advanceTask);
        console.log(advanceTask);
        displayTasks();
}
```

If you take a look at the "advanceTask" variable, my intention is to advance the numerical value stored in "taskTracker" each time this function is invoked. However, all I'm getting is an additional "1" appended to the value each time.

Thoughts? <3

Comment: `task` and `taskNumber` at `var taskNumber = localStorage.getItem("taskTracker")` are strings.

Comment: @guest271314 I appreciate you pointing out the obvious?

Comment: `+` operator can convert a string to a number. `+task`, `+taskNumber`

Comment: `"1" + 1 !== 2`

Comment: @guest271314 AH, now I see what you're saying. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `string` + `number` and `number` + `number`. Your current solution is like the `stringPlusOne` function below. You need to convert the string to a number (using `parseInt` is one way) and then do the math, like the `stringPlusOne2` function below

```js
function stringPlusOne(str) {
  console.log(str + 1);
}

function stringPlusOne2(str) {
  console.log(parseInt(str, 10) + 1);
}

stringPlusOne("2");
stringPlusOne2("2");
```